# Possible to create a calculated field in a doctrine query you can then retrieve as an object attribute?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Suppose you declare a simple "license" table in a doctrine schema, consisting say of 3 fields, `name, licenseNumber, expirationDate`.

You can create a simple query to instantiate the collection of license objects. But what if you wanted to add a "virtual" field to it, for example,`select *, (now() > expirationDate) as expired from license` (in DQL, I'm using SQL as shorthand here).

Is there any way to get doctrine to make the "expired" calculated field retrievable as an attribute of the object? This is a trivial example to illustrate the point, but it could be quite helpful for more complicated calculated queries, or else I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Which version of symfony and doctrine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do what you are asking without adding a custom method to hydrate the "virtual column". Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890933/adding-virtual-columns-to-current-table-in-doctrine), as it gives an excellent example on how to hydrate arrays with your "virtual column".

You can also add the "virtual column" as a member object to the respective class and hydrate it like this [example](http://melikedev.com/2009/10/07/symfony-w-propel-table-joins-manual-object-hydration/) demonstrates.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the custom hydration?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a view with such a column and map your model to it instead of a db table