# Use a calculated column in a doctrine2 mapping definition

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Is it possible in doctrine2 to use a calculated column in the mapping definition? I have for example a table that has a column called `quantity` and a column `unit_price`. I want to add a calculated column `price` to the mapping which will be calculated by multiplying `quantity` and `unit_price`. I know that this will only be possible for SELECT statements.

Could this be achieved using doctrine2?

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done with doctrine explicitly.

1. You have two alternate approaches:  Customize the entity that is instanced via doctrine query with a property that has no representation in the database, and use the constructor to calculate the value.
2. Use a custom hydrator.  See: [Adding virtual columns to current table in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890933/adding-virtual-columns-to-current-table-in-doctrine).

Comment: The question is about Doctrine2, and the answer points to the question about Doctrine1... Don't get why it is chosen.

Comment: In the grossest sense, the method is the same for both versions.

Comment: Option 1 will not work in Doctrine 2, since the constructors are only called when creating new instances. Retrieving an instance of an existing object in Doctrine 2 does not cause the constructor to be called. http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/21/doctrine-2-give-me-my-constructor-back.html